# Set of $52$ integers, Dirichlet's principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that in any set of $52$ integers we can find at least $2$ numbers, summation or subtraction of which will be divided by $100$.

Comment: By _"as minimum 2 numbers"_, do you mean _at least 2 numbers_?

Comment: as minimum = at least

Comment: Consider the residues (modulo 100) of those 52 numbers. Then by pigeonhole principle, there will a pair of numbers, say, $(a, b)$ such that either $a \equiv b \mod 100$ or $a \equiv -b \mod 100$. Now, in the first case $a-b$ will be divisible by 100 and in the second case, $a+b$ will be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the ''boxes''

$\{0,100\}$; $\{1,99\}$; $\{2,98\}$;... $\{49,51\}$ and $\{50\}$

Then put a number in box $\{i,100-i\}$ if it has a remainder $i$ or $100-i$ when divided by $100$.

Then in one box there are at least two numbers (since we have 51 boxes) and thus conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** The fact that we have a "$52$" floating around in the question suggests that we should be looking for a set of $51$ equivalence classes, such that any two integers falling into the same equivalence class will satisfy the requirement.  Since there are $52$ integers in all, *some* pair of integers that are satisfactory must exist.

Thus, determining what those equivalence classes are if your task.  For instance, one equivalence class must contain both $8$ and $308$, since their difference is $300$, which is divisible by $100$.  But just relying on equivalence modulo $100$ won't work; that requires $100$ equivalence classes.  What can you do to cut the number of classes down to $51$?

Comment: Will the classes be those generated by the relation $(a \equiv b \lor a \equiv -b) \mod 100$?

Comment: @feynhat: They might!